# get pandas value by another file python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H578','H600', 'H700'],
  'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it looks like:

```
Out[76]: 
    CD    ID
0  AAAAAAA  H576
1    BBBBB  H577
2   CCCCCC  H578
3   DDDDDD  H600
4  EEEEEEE  H700
```

i also have a small .txt file :

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBB
EEEEEEE
```

I want to loop through the 'CD' column from the dataframe and the .txt file, if there is a match, print out the ID and the CD in a .txt file.

desire output, output.txt:

```
H576
AAAAAAA
H577
BBBBB
H700
EEEEEEE
```

my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H578','H600', 'H700'],
  'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE']}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
f = open('file.txt') 

for i in data.CD:
    i = i.strip()    
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()

        if df["CD"].str.contains(line).any():
            position = df.index.get_indexer_for((df[df["CD"].str.contains(line)].index))
            z = df.ReadID[position]
            print(z)
            print(line)
```

this is not quite right and i think i might be over thinking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H578','H600', 'H700'],
      'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
keywords = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)[0]

mask = df['CD'].isin(keywords)
result = df.loc[mask]
print(result[['ID', 'CD']].stack().to_csv(None, index=False))
```

yields

```
H576
AAAAAAA
H577
BBBBB
H700
EEEEEEE
```

---

- `pd.read_csv` loads `file.txt` into a DataFrame. You can then select the single column in the DataFrame to define the Series `keywords`:

  ```
  keywords = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)[0]
  ```
- The `Series.isin` method can then be used to construct a boolean Series which is True when the value in `df['CD']` is in `keywords`:

  ```
  mask = df['CD'].isin(keywords)
  # 0     True
  # 1     True
  # 2    False
  # 3    False
  # 4     True
  ```
- Use `df.loc[mask]` to select the rows of `df` where `mask` is True:

  ```
  result = df.loc[mask]
  #         CD    ID
  # 0  AAAAAAA  H576
  # 1    BBBBB  H577
  # 4  EEEEEEE  H700
  ```
- Finally, the desired string can be formed using `df.to_csv`. By passing `None` as the first argument `df.to_csv` a string is returned (instead of writing to a file)